# How to copy and paste textboxes from one sheet to another by automatically opening a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to copy and paste a few textboxes from one sheet to a new one. The macro listed below works well in a new fresh workbook:

```
Sub Move_controls()
 Dim sh As Shape
 Dim T, L As Integer
 Sheets("MasterCopy").Select
     For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
     If sh.Type <> msoComment Then
         T = sh.Top
         L = sh.Left         
         For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            If Sheet.Name <> "MasterCopy" Then
                 sh.Copy
                    Sheet.Select
                    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Link:=False,      
                DisplayAsIcon:=False
                sh.Select
                Selection.Top = T
                Selection.Left = L         
            End If
         Next
     End If
     Sheets("MasterCopy").Select
     Next
 End Sub
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work when I try to nest it to a macro that opens automatically a new sheet by copying a sheet called MasterCopy sheet in to a new one.

Here you go the other macro that opens automatically a new sheet copying and pasting the MasterCopy sheet with all its features.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal sh As Object)
        Dim tmpName As String
        tmpName = sh.Name
        Sheets("MasterCopy").Copy Before:=Sheets(sh.Name)
             Application.DisplayAlerts = False
             Sheets(sh.Name).Delete
             Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Sheets("MasterCopy (2)").Name = tmpName    
    End Sub
```

Have you got any suggestion on how to nest these two codes and copy and paste MasterCopy sheet with all its textboxes and features?

Comment: Why not just copy the whole sheet and then delete things you don't want?

Comment: Please do you mean doing that manually or by using a macro?

Comment: I meant with code

Comment: Please can you show me an example?

Comment: If you record a macro whilst doing the move and delete you will get the main elements.

Comment: Anything can be done instead by nesting the two macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through objects on Activesheet and changing activesheet within the loop may lead to confusions. I would also revise `sh.Select` as it refers to the current shape on MasterCopy, so it makes no change to set the position in the next 2 lines. 
So you may consider the following improvements:

```
Dim T as integer, L As Integer
For Each sh In Sheets("MasterCopy").Shapes
...
    ' instead of sh.Select +2 lines: 
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(sh.name).Top = sh.Top
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(sh.name).Left = sh.Left
```

I can't see the nested code but I can also presume a confusion with sh being either a shape or a sheet.

Still, I do not really understand why you need to copy the shapes one by one when you copy the entire sheet...

Comment: I would prefer the last option you said in the last sentence. That would be much easier. The problem is the Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet macro copies everything in the new sheet except the textboxes. Do you know the reason why?

Comment: I would check the `For Each sh In Sheets("MasterCopy").Shapes` 
loop step by step to see what shapes are there in the collection, e.g. putting this line straight below For Each: `Debug.print sh.name & ", " & sh.type`. I've tested it on my sheet: when I insert a textbox, it will be inserted into the collection of Shapes.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thanks a lot. It works fine in this way.